# How to check if the value is present in the array of inputs

Tags: html, ajax

Here is my code

i have an input textbox where I get a new value

this line doesn't work,

```js
  $(document).on('click', '#af_cbms_add_depID', function() 
        {  
            var toclone=$("#newdepID").val();
            var torefer=$("#af_cbms_question_item").val();
              if((toclone!=='') && (toclone>0))
                  { 

                      ///here's the problem

                          $(".lahatkami").each(function()
                               {

                                   input = $(this).val();
                            
                                   //i also tried the other
                                   //if(this.value===toclone)
                                   if(input===toclone) 
                                        {
                                            alert("There is a duplicate value " + this.value);
                                            $('#newdepID').val('');
                                            $('#newdepID').focus();
                                            return false;
                                        }                  
            
                                  else
                                       {
                                            $("#af_cbms_depIDset").append('<input type="text" name="'+torefer+'" id="depID'+toclone+'" class="lahatkami" value="'+toclone+'" style="width:40px !important; text-align:center;" readonly />');
                                            $('#newdepID').val('');
                                            $('#newdepID').focus();
                                      }
                               });


                  }
              else
                  {
                   alert('No dependent question item was set!');
                   $('#newdepID').focus();
                  }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="textbox" id="newdepID" value="3"/> sample we a number 3 value

    <button id="af_cbms_add_depID">Submit</button> //submits the value

    //here are the inputs
    <input type="textbox" class="lahatkami" id="newdepID" value="3"/>
    <input type="textbox" class="lahatkami" id="newdepID" value="5"/>
    <input type="textbox" class="lahatkami" id="newdepID" value="4"/>
```

after clicking submit i already coded it if the text input is empty.
   but inside that if not empty i check again if the value is already in the set of inputs

i put a console.log to check inside but not working

Comment: What does `$(".lahatkami")` this return?

Comment: i have tested your code and its working. check if  you have an error on page load.

Comment: this  $(".lahatkami") are the classes of the inputs and i get values of the inputs with that class

Comment: also on page id must be unique identity in your code there are 4 place where u used same id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to this..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#af_cbms_add_depID" ).click(function()
        {
            var toclone= $("#newdepID").val();
            var torefer=$("#af_cbms_question_item").val();
            if((toclone!=='') && (toclone > 0)) {
                  $(".lahatkami").each(function() {
                           input = $(this).val();
                           //alert(input);
                           if(input===toclone)
                            {
                                alert("There is a duplicate value " + this.value);
                                $('#newdepID').val('');
                                $('#newdepID').focus();
                                return false;
                            }else {
                                $("#af_cbms_depIDset").append('<input type="text" name="'+torefer+'" id="depID'+toclone+'" class="lahatkami" value="'+toclone+'" style="width:40px !important; text-align:center;" readonly />');
                                $('#newdepID').val('');
                                $('#newdepID').focus();
                            }
                    });
            } else {
               alert('No dependent question item was set!');
               $('#newdepID').focus();
            }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: this seem to work i just improve it, by adding var duplicatecount=0; before $(".lahatkami").each(function() {    and add increments inside this if(this.value===toclone)  { duplicatecount++; then instead of putting else i make another if like if(duplicatecount==0){  //here the append   outside this line $(".lahatkami").each(function(){  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i am not clear with you exact requirement but i think below is code whic you looking for.

```
$(document).on('click', '#af_cbms_add_depID', function(){  
    var toclone=$("#newdepID").val();
    var torefer=$("#af_cbms_question_item").val();
    $("#af_cbms_depIDset").html("");
    if((toclone!=='') && (toclone>0)){ 
        var $tmpdom = $("<span></span>");
        $(".lahatkami").each(function(){
           input = $(this).val();
           if(input===toclone){
                    alert("There is a duplicate value " + this.value);
                    $(this).val('');
                    $(this).focus();
                    return;
           }else {  
               $tmpdom.append('<input type="text" name="'+torefer+'" id="depID'+toclone+'" class="lahatkami" value="'+toclone+'" style="width:40px !important; text-align:center;" readonly />');
           }
        });
        $("#af_cbms_depIDset").append($tmpdom.html());

      }else{
           alert('No dependent question item was set!');
           $('#newdepID').focus();
     }
});
```

Comment: it works but it still add even if the value exist before the alert it generates the input,  i think it does not break in after the alert it still adds up input. even if i put return false; the alert is working if there is duplicate value.